# How to fill in a 2D array by equating it to a function with void parameters?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 2d

I'm making a little minigame with the use of a 2D array. I tried making a function that starts you off with a clean board and want it in such a way that the cleanboard function is an rvalue if that makes sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 8
#define EMPTY 0
#define BLACK 1
#define WHITE -1


//Fills the 2D array with 0s and places the 4 starting pieces in the middle
int **cleanboard(void){
    int newboard[MAX][MAX];
    (*newboard)[MAX] = malloc(sizeof*newboard*MAX);

    for(int row=0; row<MAX; row++){
        for(int col=0; col<MAX; col++){
            newboard[row][col] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    newboard[3][3] = WHITE, newboard[4][4] = WHITE;
    newboard[4][3] = BLACK, newboard[3][4] = BLACK;

    return newboard;
}


//Displays the board
void printboard(int arr[][MAX]){
    printf("   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n");               //Top numbers

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<MAX; j++){
            if(j==0){printf("%d ", i+1);}        //Side numbers
            switch(arr[i][j]){                   //Print piece
            case 0: printf(" .");
                    break;
            case 1: printf(" b");
                    break;
            case -1: printf(" w");
                    break;
            }
        }
     printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(){
    int **board;
    board = cleanboard();
    printboard(board);
    return 0;
}
```

With the given code, it outputs:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1
```

However, this example is how the board should look:

```
//Example 2D array:

int grid[MAX][MAX] = {{-1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0},
                      {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1},
                      {1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1},
                      {1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                      {0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1},
                      {1, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1},
                      {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0}};

printboard(grid);
```

Output:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1  w b w b . w b .
2  b w w b . w w b
3  b b w b w b b b
4  w . w w w b b w
5  b w . b . b . .
6  . b w b w w b w
7  b b b w . w w w
8  . w w w w b w .
```

The cleanboard function isn't storing the values or something which causes the printboard function to stop.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fyi, `int **` isn't an array of arrays; it's a pointer to pointer. It is *not* synonymous with an array MAX of array MAX of `int`. They're different constructs. One *looks* like an array of array, and uses identical syntactic sugar in code with appearance of index operators [] etc, the other actually *is* an array of arrays. But worst of all, you're not only returning the wrong type, you're returning a base address of an expiring object in local function scope. Even if you fixed the type issue, that problem alone will invoke *undefined behavior* on dereference through the returned address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter type for `printboard` is what you want.  However, the conversion of arrays to pointers only occurs with the first dimension of a multi-dimmensional array.  You're attempting to convert between a `int (*)[MAX]` and a `int **` which are not the same thing.

In `cleanboard`, you need to define `newboard` as:

```
int (*newboard)[MAX] = malloc(sizeof*newboard*MAX);
```

Then the function itself should be defined as:

```
int (*cleanboard(void))[MAX] {
```

And `board` in `main` should be defined as:

```
int (*board)[MAX];
```

Also, you'll want to print a newline in `printboard` after the inner loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code :

1. creates the board
2. initializes the board

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 8
#define EMPTY 0
#define BLACK 1
#define WHITE -1


//Fills the 2D array with 0s and places the 4 starting pieces in the middle
int **cleanboard(void)
{
    int **newboard = malloc( MAX * sizeof( int ) );;

    for(int row=0; row<MAX; row++)
    { 
         newboard[row] = malloc( MAX * sizeof( int ) );
    }
    
    for(int row=0; row<MAX; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<MAX; col++)
        {
            newboard[row][col] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    newboard[3][3] = WHITE;
    newboard[4][4] = WHITE;
    newboard[4][3] = BLACK;
    newboard[3][4] = BLACK;

    return newboard;
}
```